# How can I get the return from an If statement whilst testing the condition?

Tags: javascript, string, if-statement, conditional-statements, refactoring

Hey there out of curiosity this is a problem I've run into several times as a noob programmer. On occasion I have to write a line like this `string.match(regExp)` but I may then store that match, all good so far `let matchedString = string.match(regExp)`, but I don't want to store a value if no match is found (this problem also applies to situations outside of strings or regular expressions).

I have to use an if statement to check the result of that line then: `if(string.match(regExp)`,but then I have to write code that seems convoluted to store the value; `if(string.match(regExp)) matchedString = string.match(regExp);` needlessly repeating the initial function. Is there a workaround to this? Or a simple general solution that I've missed?

Comment: Use the or operator: let string = string.match(regExp) || 'default string'

Comment: @tsgrgo that would defeat the purpose of _"I don't want to store a value if no match is found"_.

Comment: @Andy what do you mean by not storing a value? Like this? string = string.match(regExp) || string

Comment: I didn't ask the question @tsgrgo

Answer (score 0):

If you don't want to store the value,

```
let matchedString = string.match(regExp) || null;
```

Answer (score 0):

As anyhow you are going to store a matched results in a variable, You have to declare that variable somewhere either globally or locally. At that time compiler automatically allocates memory for it. This is known as compile time memory allocation or static memory allocation.

Now coming to your question - By default, If no matches happen [`String.match()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/match) will return `null` and as variable already taken the memory so there is no harm to assign `null` to it if there is no matches happen.

Live Demo **:**

```js
var str = 'alpha';

const res = str.match(/[0-9]/g);

console.log(res); // null
```